# Not quite understanding defining constructors in classes

Tags: c++, class

So I'm a little confused about how this works. I've followed other examples to come up with the following:

```
//in entity.h
#pragma once

class Entity
{
    int nEntity;
};


//in entity.cpp
#include "entity.h"

Entity::Entity
{
    nEntity = 5;
}
```

and I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't like it. Any hints?

Comment: You are defining a constructor, but you haven't declared it within the class.

Comment: Just so you are aware, this isn't called forward declaration.

Comment: Ah, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create what is called a "constructor," which is a function called to create new copies of `Entity`.  There's two things to fix here:

- First off, you need to forward declare your constructor.  Otherwise, C++ doesn't know your class has one until it's too late.  This seems a little wonky at first, but once you start using multiple cpp files, you'll see it makes more sense.
- Second, your constructor needs arguments.  It's just a syntax change.

This should work:

```
class Entity
{
    public: // by default, everything is "private" and only available to
            // Entity itself.  By adding this line here, everything that
            // follows can be used anywhere
        Entity();    // this "forward declares" that you're going to have a
                     // constructor with no arguments

        int nEntity; // usually variables are marked "private," but I have a
                     // feeling you'll want to keep it public for a bit, until
                     // you get used to classes

};

Entity::Entity()
{
    nEntity = 5;
}
```

And, as an extra credit effort, you can also use the special notation for assigning values to class members which is only available in constructors (no other functions can use this notation).  They have a few advantages which are rather tricky to explain, but if you get in the habit of using this notation, it'll be helpful to you later

```
Entity::Entity()
: nEntity(5)
{
    // no extra instructions here.  The assignment was done on the
    // line starting with a colon!
}
```

Comment: Constructors don't necessarily create new copies, and this isn't forward declaration.

Comment: Constructors create new objects of a type.  Perhaps "copy" was the wrong word because that does have another meaning that you are alluding to, but I didn't think it'd lead too far from the truth.  However, are you sure it is not forward declaration of a function?   I know it's not forward declaration of the class, but I thought I was using correct terminology claiming we are forward declaring the function.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Neil, I changed the title to avoid further confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of problems.

1. You haven't declared the constructor in the class.
2. In the definition, you have left out the parentheses.

In the .h file:

```
class Entity
{
   Entity();    // Add this.
   int nEntity;
};
```

In the .cpp file:

```
Entity::Entity() // Need the parentheses
{
    nEntity = 5;
}
```